# matplotlib matshow labels

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, label

I start using matplotlib a month ago, so I'm still learning.
I'm trying to do a heatmap with matshow. My code is the following:

```
data = numpy.array(a).reshape(4, 4)  
cax = ax.matshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.get_cmap('PuBu'), norm=LogNorm())  
cbar = fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(alpha)  
ax.set_yticklabels(alpha)
```

where alpha is a model from django with 4fields: 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'

the thing is that I don't know why, the label 'ABC' doesn't appear, leaving the last cell without label.
If someone would have a clue how to modify my script in a way to appear the 'ABC' I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What's happening is that the xticks actually extend outside of the displayed figure when using matshow.  (I'm not quite sure exactly why this is. I've almost never used matshow, though.)

To demonstrate this, look at the output of `ax.get_xticks()`. In your case, it's `array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])`.  Therefore, when you set the xtick labels, "ABC" is at <-1, -1>, and isn't displayed on the figure.

The easiest solution is just to prepend a blank label to your list of labels, e.g.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)
```

As a full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']

data = np.random.random((4,4))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)

plt.show()
```

[image: Matshow example]

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to see the same thing :)

But I've another problem..I'm doing two heatmaps, one (4x4) and another(9x9). The program label the heatmap 0,2,4,6,8.. So when I tried to label, it only gives a name to those numbers.

I've tried with ax.set_xticks(matplotlib.numpy.arange(len(list_names))) 
but it decrease the size of cells..

Comment: @Patricia - If you set the tick locations manually, a call to `ax.axis('image')` after you set them should fix the problem you described.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved :)
So ax.axis('image') restore the original size of the image, right?

Comment: Basically.  (I'm honestly not sure why the axis limits change when the tick locations are set... This might be a bug...)  See here for more information on what `ax.axis('image')` does: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis

Answer (score 11):

The other way to do this is to specify the ticks, and then set the corresponding labels.  Then you don't have to worry about the extra out of bounds tick.  This comes up in lots of matplotlib demos.  So here, note the extra calls the `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_yticks`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL']

data = np.random.random((4,4))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
fig.colorbar(cax)

xaxis = np.arange(len(alpha))
ax.set_xticks(xaxis)
ax.set_yticks(xaxis)
ax.set_xticklabels(alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(alpha)

plt.show()
```

[image]