# sklearn plot confusion matrix with labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I want to plot a confusion matrix to visualize the classifer's performance, but it shows only the numbers of the labels, not the labels themselves:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pylab as pl
y_test=['business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business']

pred=array(['health', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'business', 'health', 'health', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'health', 'health', 'business', 'health'], 
      dtype='|S8')

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred)
pl.matshow(cm)
pl.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier')
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
```

How can I add the labels (health, business..etc) to the confusion matrix?

Comment: Very simple solution and even without sklearn but prints the labels `pandas.crosstab(y_test, pred, rownames=['True'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As hinted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529666/matplotlib-matshow-labels), you have to "open" the [lower-level artist API](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html#artist-tutorial), by storing the figure and axis objects passed by the matplotlib functions you call (the `fig`, `ax` and `cax` variables below). You can then replace the default x- and y-axis ticks using `set_xticklabels`/`set_yticklabels`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

labels = ['business', 'health']
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred, labels)
print(cm)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(cm)
plt.title('Confusion matrix of the classifier')
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.set_xticklabels([''] + labels)
ax.set_yticklabels([''] + labels)
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```

Note that I passed the `labels` list to the `confusion_matrix` function to make sure it's properly sorted, matching the ticks.

This results in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: If you have more than a few categories, Matplotlib decides to label the axes incorrectly - you have to force it to label every cell.  `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator; ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1)); ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))`

Comment: Being a new one, could you tell me if the size of 3 boxes are implying the level of accuracy?

Comment: how do I display the numbers on them? since colors may not convey much in all cases

Comment: Hi...@metakermit . Could you tell how to show the numbers inside the coloured figure?

Answer (score 105):

**UPDATE:**

Check the [`ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

I think it's worth mentioning the use of [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) here.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     

ax= plt.subplot()
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g', ax=ax);  #annot=True to annotate cells, ftm='g' to disable scientific notation

# labels, title and ticks
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted labels');ax.set_ylabel('True labels'); 
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix'); 
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['business', 'health']); ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['health', 'business']);
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: pass `fmt='g'` to the `heatmap` call to keep numbers from going to scientific notation.

Comment: Suggestion: pass `cmap='Greens'` to the `heatmap` call to have intuitive color meaning.

Comment: How to be sure you're not mixing up the labels?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica When you get the `confusion_matrix`, the X axis tick labels are 1, 0 and Y axis tick labels are 0, 1 (in the axis values increasing order). If the classifier is `clf`, you can get the class order by `clf.classes_`, which should match `["health", "business"]` in this case. (It is assumed that `business` is the positive class).

Answer (score 49):

To add to @akilat90's update about `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix`:

You can use the `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` class within `sklearn.metrics` directly and bypass the need to pass a classifier to `plot_confusion_matrix`. It also has the `display_labels` argument, which allows you to specify the labels displayed in the plot as desired.

The constructor for `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` doesn't provide a way to do much additional customization of the plot, but you can access the matplotlib axes obect via the `ax_` attribute after calling its `plot()` method. I've added a second example showing this.

I found it annoying to have to rerun a classifier over a large amount of data just to produce the plot with `plot_confusion_matrix`. I am producing other plots off the predicted data, so I don't want to waste my time re-predicting every time. This was an easy solution to that problem as well.

Example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_preds, normalize='all')
cmd = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=['business','health'])
cmd.plot()
```

[image: confusion matrix example 1]

Example using `ax_`:

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_preds, normalize='all')
cmd = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=['business','health'])
cmd.plot()
cmd.ax_.set(xlabel='Predicted', ylabel='True')
```

[image: confusion matrix example]

Comment: This is excellent - thanks! Question: Can you customize 'True label' and 'Predicted label' values for the axis labels?

Comment: I didn't realize this before, but you can access the matplotlib axes object via `cmd.ax_`, which allows a lot of control of the plot.  To customize the axis labels use something like this: `cmd.ax_.set(xlabel='foo', ylabel='bar')` . I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it looks like the `cmd.ax_.set` disables the `display_labels=['business','health']` ?

Comment: Also I'm getting `AttributeError: 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay' object has no attribute 'ax_' `.

Comment: Ah, you are right! Thanks for pointing those things out. In my excitement to find the solution I made a few mistakes in my update. Please see the latest version, it should work now.

Comment: "I found it annoying to have to rerun a classifier over a large amount of data just to produce the plot with plot_confusion_matrix." - I find it peculiar that this reruns the classifier and does not use the values given to it. I was getting mixed results using this and the simpler confusion_matrix(). Glad you pointed it out!

Answer (score 47):

I found a function that can plot the confusion matrix which generated from `sklearn`.

```
import numpy as np


def plot_confusion_matrix(cm,
                          target_names,
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=None,
                          normalize=True):
    """
    given a sklearn confusion matrix (cm), make a nice plot

    Arguments
    ---------
    cm:           confusion matrix from sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix

    target_names: given classification classes such as [0, 1, 2]
                  the class names, for example: ['high', 'medium', 'low']

    title:        the text to display at the top of the matrix

    cmap:         the gradient of the values displayed from matplotlib.pyplot.cm
                  see http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
                  plt.get_cmap('jet') or plt.cm.Blues

    normalize:    If False, plot the raw numbers
                  If True, plot the proportions

    Usage
    -----
    plot_confusion_matrix(cm           = cm,                  # confusion matrix created by
                                                              # sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix
                          normalize    = True,                # show proportions
                          target_names = y_labels_vals,       # list of names of the classes
                          title        = best_estimator_name) # title of graph

    Citiation
    ---------
    http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html

    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import itertools

    accuracy = np.trace(cm) / np.sum(cm).astype('float')
    misclass = 1 - accuracy

    if cmap is None:
        cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()

    if target_names is not None:
        tick_marks = np.arange(len(target_names))
        plt.xticks(tick_marks, target_names, rotation=45)
        plt.yticks(tick_marks, target_names)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]


    thresh = cm.max() / 1.5 if normalize else cm.max() / 2
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        if normalize:
            plt.text(j, i, "{:0.4f}".format(cm[i, j]),
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
        else:
            plt.text(j, i, "{:,}".format(cm[i, j]),
                     horizontalalignment="center",
                     color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")


    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label\naccuracy={:0.4f}; misclass={:0.4f}'.format(accuracy, misclass))
    plt.show()
```

It will look like this
[image]

Comment: How would this work with more than 3 classes?

Comment: @Kurt, when you have more than 3 classes, you just get a larger confusion matrix (i.e. a 10 x 10 matrix if you have 10 classes). NB: The `target_names` variable through which you pass the labels of your classes to the function needs to match the number of classes in the confusion matrix.

Answer (score 31):

```
from sklearn import model_selection
test_size = 0.33
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(feature_vectors, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
result = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Accuracy: %.3f%%" % (result*100.0))
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("F1 Score: ", f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))
print("Precision Score: ", precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))
print("Recall Score: ", recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro")) 

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def cm_analysis(y_true, y_pred, labels, ymap=None, figsize=(10,10)):
    """
    Generate matrix plot of confusion matrix with pretty annotations.
    The plot image is saved to disk.
    args: 
      y_true:    true label of the data, with shape (nsamples,)
      y_pred:    prediction of the data, with shape (nsamples,)
      filename:  filename of figure file to save
      labels:    string array, name the order of class labels in the confusion matrix.
                 use `clf.classes_` if using scikit-learn models.
                 with shape (nclass,).
      ymap:      dict: any -> string, length == nclass.
                 if not None, map the labels & ys to more understandable strings.
                 Caution: original y_true, y_pred and labels must align.
      figsize:   the size of the figure plotted.
    """
    if ymap is not None:
        # change category codes or labels to new labels 
        y_pred = [ymap[yi] for yi in y_pred]
        y_true = [ymap[yi] for yi in y_true]
        labels = [ymap[yi] for yi in labels]
    # calculate a confusion matrix with the new labels
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=labels)
    # calculate row sums (for calculating % & plot annotations)
    cm_sum = np.sum(cm, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    # calculate proportions
    cm_perc = cm / cm_sum.astype(float) * 100
    # empty array for holding annotations for each cell in the heatmap
    annot = np.empty_like(cm).astype(str)
    # get the dimensions
    nrows, ncols = cm.shape
    # cycle over cells and create annotations for each cell
    for i in range(nrows):
        for j in range(ncols):
            # get the count for the cell
            c = cm[i, j]
            # get the percentage for the cell
            p = cm_perc[i, j]
            if i == j:
                s = cm_sum[i]
                # convert the proportion, count, and row sum to a string with pretty formatting
                annot[i, j] = '%.1f%%\n%d/%d' % (p, c, s)
            elif c == 0:
                annot[i, j] = ''
            else:
                annot[i, j] = '%.1f%%\n%d' % (p, c)
    # convert the array to a dataframe. To plot by proportion instead of number, use cm_perc in the DataFrame instead of cm
    cm = pd.DataFrame(cm, index=labels, columns=labels)
    cm.index.name = 'Actual'
    cm.columns.name = 'Predicted'
    # create empty figure with a specified size
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    # plot the data using the Pandas dataframe. To change the color map, add cmap=..., e.g. cmap = 'rocket_r'
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=annot, fmt='', ax=ax)
    #plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()

cm_analysis(y_test, y_pred, model.classes_, ymap=None, figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

using https://gist.github.com/hitvoice/36cf44689065ca9b927431546381a3f7

Note that if you use `rocket_r` it will reverse the colors and somehow it looks more natural and better such as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but what's the `rocket_r` option you mentioned?

Comment: in the function `sns.heatmap()`, pass argument `cmap='rocket_r'` for color inverse of the scale

Comment: How that's amazing

Answer (score 23):

You might be interested by
https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml/

which implements a Python Pandas implementation of Confusion Matrix.

Some features:

- plot confusion matrix
- plot normalized confusion matrix
- class statistics
- overall statistics

Here is an example:

```
In [1]: from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: y_test = ['business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
        'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
        'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
        'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business']

In [4]: y_pred = ['health', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'business', 'health', 'health', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'business', 'business', 'business', 'business', 'business',
       'health', 'health', 'business', 'health']

In [5]: cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_test, y_pred)

In [6]: cm
Out[6]:
Predicted  business  health  __all__
Actual
business         14       6       20
health            0       0        0
__all__          14       6       20

In [7]: cm.plot()
Out[7]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1093cf9b0>

In [8]: plt.show()
```

[image: Plot confusion matrix]

```
In [9]: cm.print_stats()
Confusion Matrix:

Predicted  business  health  __all__
Actual
business         14       6       20
health            0       0        0
__all__          14       6       20


Overall Statistics:

Accuracy: 0.7
95% CI: (0.45721081772371086, 0.88106840959427235)
No Information Rate: ToDo
P-Value [Acc > NIR]: 0.608009812201
Kappa: 0.0
Mcnemar's Test P-Value: ToDo


Class Statistics:

Classes                                 business health
Population                                    20     20
P: Condition positive                         20      0
N: Condition negative                          0     20
Test outcome positive                         14      6
Test outcome negative                          6     14
TP: True Positive                             14      0
TN: True Negative                              0     14
FP: False Positive                             0      6
FN: False Negative                             6      0
TPR: (Sensitivity, hit rate, recall)         0.7    NaN
TNR=SPC: (Specificity)                       NaN    0.7
PPV: Pos Pred Value (Precision)                1      0
NPV: Neg Pred Value                            0      1
FPR: False-out                               NaN    0.3
FDR: False Discovery Rate                      0      1
FNR: Miss Rate                               0.3    NaN
ACC: Accuracy                                0.7    0.7
F1 score                               0.8235294      0
MCC: Matthews correlation coefficient        NaN    NaN
Informedness                                 NaN    NaN
Markedness                                     0      0
Prevalence                                     1      0
LR+: Positive likelihood ratio               NaN    NaN
LR-: Negative likelihood ratio               NaN    NaN
DOR: Diagnostic odds ratio                   NaN    NaN
FOR: False omission rate                       1      0
```

Comment: What, how did you get this to work?  With the latest pandas_ml it's giving me a blank confusion matrix (all 0's), and the labels are True/False instead of business and health.

Comment: the same, it is blank

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'jaccard_similarity_score' with scikit-learn version 0.23.1 and pandas-ml version 0.6.1. I have tried other versions as well with no luck.

Comment: How did you turn the x-axis labels diagonal?

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml/blob/26717cc33ddc3548b023a6410b2235fb21a7b382/pandas_ml/confusion_matrix/abstract.py#L235

Answer (score 13):

```
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    model.fit(train_x, train_y,validation_split = 0.1, epochs=50, batch_size=4)
    y_pred=model.predict(test_x,batch_size=15)
    cm =confusion_matrix(test_y.argmax(axis=1), y_pred.argmax(axis=1))  
    index = ['neutral','happy','sad']  
    columns = ['neutral','happy','sad']  
    cm_df = pd.DataFrame(cm,columns,index)                      
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))  
    sns.heatmap(cm_df, annot=True)
```

[image: Confusion matrix]

Answer (score 10):

There is a very easy way to do this using `ConfusionMatrixDisplay`. It supports  `display_labels` which can be used to display labels for plot

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
np.random.seed(0)
y_true = np.random.randint(0,3, 100)
y_pred = np.random.randint(0,3, 100)

labels = ['cat', 'dog', 'rat']

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=labels).plot()
#plt.savefig("Confusion_Matrix.png")
```

Output:

[image]

Ref: [ConfusionMatrixDisplay](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)

## Edit 1:

To changes the X-axis labels to vertical position (needed when class labels are overlapping in the plot) and also plotting directly from predictions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
np.random.seed(0)

n = 10
y_true = np.random.randint(0,n, 100)
y_pred = np.random.randint(0,n, 100)

labels = [f'class_{i+1}' for i in range(n)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions(
    y_true, y_pred, display_labels=labels, xticks_rotation="vertical",
    ax=ax, colorbar=False, cmap="plasma")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you! Is there a way to represent the X-axis labels in a vertical fashion? I am using a multiclass evaluation so my labels are getting overlapped with one another when I want to show the confusion matrix.

Comment: Could you tell how can I set the label on the top of the figure? it was ax.xaxis.tick_top() in seaborn but now I see no way to do it in the official scikitlearn page. Thank you :)

Comment: @raiyan22 `ax.xaxis.tick_top()` should work. Call just after creating `subplots`

Answer (score 3):

Given model, validx, validy. With great help from other answers, this is what fits my needs.

[sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(26,26))
sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix(model, validx, validy, ax=ax, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
ax.set(xlabel='Predicted', ylabel='Actual', title='Confusion Matrix Actual vs Predicted')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel="linear", C=0.01).fit(X_train, y_train)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_estimator(
       classifier,
       X_test,
       y_test,
       display_labels=class_names,
       cmap=plt.cm.Blues,`enter code here`
       normalize=normalize,
)
    
disp.ax_.set_title(title) # this line is your answer
    
plt.show()
```