# Why is sklearn Confusion Matrix plot stacking everything in the left column?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, heatmap, confusion-matrix, sequential

I am trying to create a confusion matrix for a Sequential model. This is what I have right now.

```
cleaned_pokedex = pd.read_csv('cleaned_pokedex.csv')
labels = sorted(cleaned_pokedex['Type1'].unique())

pred_y = model.predict(test_x)

confusion = confusion_matrix(true_y, np.argmax(pred_y, axis=1))
_, axis = plt.subplots(figsize = (12, 10))

sns.heatmap(confusion,
            annot = True,
            fmt = 'd',
            xticklabels = labels,
            yticklabels = labels,
            ax = axis)

plt.xlabel('Prediction')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.show()
```

It's resulting in this:

[image: CM for NN]

As you can see, all of the data points are stuck on predicting Bug (which they aren't actually always predicting Bug). Any ideas? I feel like it's really small but I've been changing things and can't figure it out.

EDIT: Clarification - There is nothing wrong with the model / classifier. It is achieving a score of 42% with model.evaluate(). It is not a problem with the heatmap either, as it shows the same thing when I print 'confusion'. There is a problem with the line where I create the confusion matrix.

EDIT2: I was wrong, I will make a different question because I've never seen this problem before. Somehow evaluate and predict are achieving two different pred_y's. Evaluate is predicting it fine, but predict is predicting all 0's, really weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sklearn plot confusion matrix with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233771/sklearn-plot-confusion-matrix-with-labels)

Comment: Is your issue with the classifier, the actual construction of the confusion matrix, or the plotting? If it's wth the classifier, we can't help because you haven't shown the code. Either way, you might like simplify down to a 3x3 or 4x4 confusion matrix (Bug, Normal, Grass,...) to help your debugging.

Comment: Also you need to add the missing imports for [`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) , seabornm etc. to make this code executable.

Comment: It seems like the model is actually predicting everything as Bug, and so the issue is most likely with the model , maybe the train test split was not 'stratified' ?